# Java How to write a text file in a jar

Tags: java, file-io

My problem is:

I do not find ways to write a txt file, which I put in my jar file

I looked different tutorial but they say it is not feasible

I appeal to you if someone can give me another solution

A tutorial to follow to solve my problem

Good day to all

Comment: This is to let you know that your question is being down voted just because you did not post your code and your question is also vague.

Comment: Addtional ressource files contained in a JAR file should be read-only. Most of the time there is no use case to store runtime configuration inside the JAR itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed this is impossible. The txt file should be provided as a resource outside the JAR.